# Removing a specific feature from the continuous integration pipeline before going to production

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

So I have a client that requested certain features to be implemented in their website. We implemented the requested features, but when showcased, the client indicated that she did not want some of the features anymore. If the builds are all integrated with each other, such that Feature A's build also contains Feature B, how can we uncouple the two features if the client wants Feature A but no longer Feature B?

I know we can rollback on commits and rebuild, but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this with a CI pipeline. We are using the Go CI tool.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolling back commits is a simple task only if the entire B feature was added on top of the completed A feature. But that is rarely the case, rolling back ops are usually not trivial because of conflicts with the A feature commits interlaced between the feature B commits and the risk of causing feature A regressions.

So really the decoupling effort (be it only to temporarily disable feature B, in case it may be needed again later, or complete removal of the feature B code) is just another set of development changes to be integrated on top of the current state of the codebase. You can consider it a new feature C (producing A minus B) :)

If properly implemented a CI system usually can help integrate software changes faster and more efficiently. In your particular case - already using a CI system - you just need to remove the verification criteria pertaining to feature B while keeping the criteria pertaining to feature A. Then proceed with integrating the decoupling sw changes just like any regular sw changes.

Comment: We ended up using feature toggles, and that was really effective.